# How to add TRX file to TFS build report

Tags: tfs, msbuild, trx

During msbuild process I get TRX-file and I want to add this file to TFS unit-tests report. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [MSDN] [To publish command-line test results to the database for the team project collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182488.aspx)

For example:

```
MSTest /publishresultsfile:testResult.trx /publish:http://ourtfsmachine:8080 /teamproject:ProjectName /publishbuild:BuildNumber01 /platform:AnyCpu /flavor:Release
```